# How to split a dataset if several columns are equal and store them as a file named by the entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data as pandas dataframe:

```
 id | name   | year | month | day | hour | minute  (+ 30 more columns like location etc.)
--------------------------------------------------
  1 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  2 | Jeff   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  3 | Elon   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  4 | Satya  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  5 | Tim    | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  6 | Mark   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  7 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
  8 | Jeff   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
  9 | Elon   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 10 | Satya  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 11 | Tim    | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 12 | Mark   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 13 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   30
                  .....
```

This dataset has around 4 million entries and was ordered by the time attributes by me already. Before it was ordered by name. The objective is to efficiently create a (parquet) file for every timeframe like this:

```
 id | name   | year | month | day | hour | minute
--------------------------------------------------
  7 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
  8 | Jeff   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
  9 | Elon   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 10 | Satya  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 11 | Tim    | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 12 | Mark   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
```

The name of the file has to be based on the time like: x_yymmddhhmm.parquet. I thought of comparing the time attributes with each other row wise. I'm completely lost at the point of combining the functionalities and that it does not take forever to process.

(.parquet would not be the most essential problem, the functionality is)

Comment: Are you looking to drop duplicates by name? `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], keep='last')`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `partition_cols` in the `pd.to_parquet()`? This will create multiple parquet files partitioned on the specified columns.